# Error with ruby update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, rbenv

I tried to update my ruby and rails version. But I ended up with this error:

```
~ ruby -v
/Users/Benjamin/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.0/libexec/rbenv:
No such file or directory
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this on OS X? You can try removing `"$(rbenv init -)"` from your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 12):

Run `rbenv rehash`

then to change / update ruby version use `rbenv` command which is ruby manager installed on your machine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `brew` you can do `brew link --overwrite ruby` and it should fix it. There might be some broken symlinks.